# Ordinal table of contents

Tags: numbering

I want create table of contents As follows:

> Chapter first (chapter name)
>
> 1.1 (section name)
>
> 1.2 (section name)
>
> 1.2.1 (subsection name)
>
> Chapter second (chapter name)
>
> 2.1 (section name)
>
> 2.1.1 (subsection name)
>
> 2.2 (section name)

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome. Where are you stuck? Having the chapter unnumbered or having the sections numbered the way they are. Or producing a `toc` in the first place?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I believe, its the ordinal numbers `first`, `second` etc, as the title of the question proposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution that depends on the `book` class, by removing patching the `\@chapter` macro, changing the `\addcontentsline` entry and setting it to `\Ordinalstring{chapter}` from `fmtcount` package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\numberline{\chaptername~\Ordinalstring{chapter} #1}}}}{}{}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some chapter name}

\section{Number one}

\subsection{Subsec Number one}


\chapter{Another chapter name}

\section{Number one from 2nd chapter}

\subsection{Subsec Number one}


\end{document}
```

[image]